# reference type as type traits / concept argument

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

In the specification-mandated implementation of the concept [`std::uniform_random_bit_generator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_random_bit_generator), it is required that invoking `operator()` on an instance of type `G` satisfying this concept should return the same type as `G::min()` and `G::max()`.

Why is `std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<G&>>` used instead of
`std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<G>>`? What the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::invocable<G&>` checks whether an lvalue of type `G` can be invoked (without arguments). `std::invocable<G>` checks whether a rvalue of type `G` can be invoked (without arguments).

`std::invoke_result_t` is equivalently the corresponding return type.

In other words this guarantees that the generator can be declared as a variable and then invoked, e.g.

```
G g{/*args*/};
auto res = g();
```

But it does not guarantee that a temporary of type `G` can be invoked directly, e.g.

```
auto res = G{/*args*/}();
```

This is not how a random number generator is commonly used.